# IE9 switch to preview in IE8 causes crash

Tags: internet-explorer-8, crash, internet-explorer-9, web-developer-toolbar

Test link: http://leongaban.com/_projects/defakto/CDS/

I'm having a strange issue, previously I was able to preview my site in IE9, 8 and 7 which allowed me to write specific stylesheets for each browser version.

This morning however, when I use IE's webdeveloper tool(F12) switch to IE8 or 7 the browser just hangs, with a generic error message "mysite is not responding". IE9 everything is fine.

Not sure what's going on, I disabled my IE8 stylesheet and even commented out my javascript file, still same issue.

IE9 version: 9.0.8112.16421

I'm also using Bootstrap 2.3.1

Anyone experience this before?

Comment: Going to ask the stupid question: you've tried completely clearing your cache?

Comment: Oh no, trying that now, I just installed some Windows updates, but still same issue...

Comment: Nope didn't work :( even emptied out my temp folders... I guess I'll try installing IE10 next.

Comment: Loading it up in actual IE8 surely does hang... I feel like it might be a JS error, but have you run your code through any validators?  By testing your site on the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fleongaban.com%2F_projects%2Fdefakto%2FCDS%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), you've got a lot of errors... you may also want to look at [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/).  I've also got your site running on [BrowserShots](http://browsershots.org/http://leongaban.com/_projects/defakto/CDS/), but it looks like it timed out.

Comment: Thx! I forgot to check that actually, just knocked out a lot of the errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the issue was, I was using css3-mediaqueries.js to support media queries for IE8 and below, I switched to respond.min.js and removed the old js and everything works now!

**Respond.js**
https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond